# Get pixel data at touch - Android/iPhone Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: javascript, image-processing, titanium, appcelerator

Is it possible to get pixel level data of an image view using Titanium Mobile on Android/iPhone?

Answer (score -1):

I guess it depends on what you mean by "Pixel-level" data.  Do you mean the literal blob of data associated with an image?  You can use the toBlog() method for the imageView: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.ImageView.toBlob-method.html